# Primary Domain Controller not syncing with secondary

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, domain-controller

Firstly, this was setup by a previous tech guy, so please forgive me if im not using the correct terms or if the setup is not best practice (trying to change that!)

We have 2 domain controllers, a primary (TITANIC) and a secondary (SERVERMCSERVERFACE)

When I make a change to our group policy, all changes appear to take place on our secondary domain controller and it never appears to sync with our PDC.

All of the client machines pull down our group policy from the PDC.

so the questions i have is

1) How can i check and ensure that our Primary domain controller is the TITANIC machine and that our secondary is SERVERMCSERVERFACE

2) How do i get these to sync the group policy between the 2.

3) For the number of clients we have (about 10) do we really need a secondary domain controller?

All servers are Windows Server 2012 r2.

Appreciate the help guys!

Comment: `When I make a change to our group policy, all changes appear to take place on our secondary domain controller and it never appears to sync with our PDC`. That's odd, considering GPMC by default uses the PDC emulator. What is the replication status?

Comment: FYI: Crossposted (there may be useful information from that thread) - https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2237104-primary-domain-controller-not-syncing-with-secondary

Comment: For anyone that wants the answer, see the spiceworks link in the comment by @Semicolon